# Google analytics with Angula and firebase/Big Query- events are missing sometimes

Tags: angular, firebase, google-bigquery, google-analytics, angularfire

I have an Angular application integrated with Firebase, and the data is exported to BigQuery.

In my Angular app, there is a requirement to send an event to analytics upon loading. However, I've noticed that only 80-90% of other events(in other application) are being tracked, even for the same user and the same device/platform, and there are no ad blockers in use.

I have attempted to use async/await to ensure that the event is sent reliably. Is this approach appropriate? Does the code appear to be correct? Is there a way to ensure that the event will always be sent?

Could it be beneficial to send another event elsewhere? Is there a potential issue with the data itself?

Is there something that can be improved in the analytics configuration itself?

When using the Analytics Debugger Chrome extension, I can see the events, but testing with external users is challenging.

In the debugger, I also notice the term 'undefined.' I'm not sure if this is related. Here's a snippet of what I see in the debugger:

```
js?l=dataLayer&id=G-XXXX:296 Sending event "event_name" to undefined
js?l=dataLayer&id=G-XXXX:296 Request parameters:
js?l=dataLayer&id=G-XXXX:296 en: event_name
js?l=dataLayer&id=G-XXXX:296 ep.origin: firebase
js?l=dataLayer&id=G-XXXX:296 ep.some_id: 12123124
js?l=dataLayer&id=G-XXXXX:296 ep.some_name: Name 123 Name

js?l=dataLayer&id=G-XXXX:296 Sending request: https://www.google-analytics.com/g/collect?v=2&tid=G-.......
```

i an using @Angular/fire (7.4) library and here is the code:

so I can i get 100% of the events

component

```
   this.test$ = this.data$.pipe(map((data) => data.test));
   this.test$.subscribe(async (test) => {
      const analyticsEvent: AnalyticsEventData = {
        some_id: string,
        some_id2: string
        some_name: string,
        some_id: string,
        some_date: firebase-timestampObject.toMillis(),
        app_name: 'string',
      };

      this.analyticsService.data = analyticsEvent;

      await this.analyticsService.custonlogEvent('event_name');
      await this.analyticsService.setUserProperties(analyticsEvent);

    });
```

any my analytics service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAnalytics } from '@angular/fire/compat/analytics';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AnalyticsService {
  constructor(private analytics: AngularFireAnalytics) {}
  private _data:AnalyticsEventData;

  get data() {
    return this._data;
  }
  set data(value) {
    this._data = value;
  }

  async customlogEvent(eventName: string, params?: { [key: string]: any }) {
    try {
      if (!this._data) throw new Error('error');

      const generalParameters = this._data;

      const paramsObject = {
        ...generalParameters,
        ...params,
      };
      await this.analytics.logEvent(eventName, paramsObject);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }

    return true;
  }

  async setUserProperties(params: { [key: string]: any }) {
    return await this.analytics.setUserProperties(params);
  }
}
```